# Problems with displaying an iframe on firefox/IE

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

I've got two iframes on a wordpress page, and I wanted it to resize itself with css, depending on screen resolution. I've came up with the code like below:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>">
    <meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0″>
</head>
<nav>
    <div id="menu-stream"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'cssmenu')); ?></div>
</nav>

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div id="infos">
                <?php 
                dynamic_sidebar('info'); 
                dynamic_sidebar('date'); 
                ?>
        </div>
        <div id="rss">
            dynamic_sidebar('rss'); 
        </div>
        <div class="entry">
                <div class="Wrapper">
                    <iframe id="video" name="video_iframe" width="854" height="480" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xxxxx?autoPlay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    <iframe id="chat" name="chat_iframe" width="380" height="480" src="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?channels=xxxx..." frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
```

Everything works fine on Chrome or Opera, but when I try out Firefox or IE, the iframes doesn't appear. I can hear the sound from dailymotion video, but it just doesn't show up.

Here is the css

```
.entry {
    color: #c5c5c5;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 11px black;
}

.Wrapper {

    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.Wrapper iframe {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}

.Wrapper#chat {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
.videoWrapper#video {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
```

I have also added some media queries. I can see that there is something wrong with:

```
.Wrapper iframe {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

because when I delete width and height it does display, but of course doesn't resize anymore. Can anybody tell me what's wrong?

Here is the article with resize solution I've decided to use
http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the updated** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nV4Je/1/)

Your problem is that your `div#entry` does not have any fixed width/height so i added some.

And too, the `position:relative` is important to your frames.

Another consideration was that i removed the `.Wrapper iframe` css because it cannot exists due to overwrite your classes `.Wrapper#video` and `.Wrapper#chat`.

**So use this CSS:**

```
.entry {
    color: #c5c5c5;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 11px black;
    width: 1250px;
    height: 500px;
}

.Wrapper {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

.Wrapper#chat {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    display: block;
}
.videoWrapper#video {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
}
```

You need it to be fluid, then, use this html for the iframes:

```
<div class="entry">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <iframe id="video" name="video_iframe" width="79%" height="500px" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xxxxx?autoPlay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            <iframe id="chat" name="chat_iframe" width="20%" height="500px" src="http://webchat.quakenet.org/?channels=xxxx..." frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

Note that i used percentage width's for the frames, and a 1% less to avoid padding problems.

Comment: (edited) oh, it does appear but it doesn't do it's job now. The whole point was to make it fluid. It doesn't work with your solution. However, the frame does display, thank you :)

Comment: "make it fluid"? tell me more what exactly do you want to do, so i can help you

Comment: To make frame adjust it's width and height depending on screen resolution (see the link http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php )

Comment: oh, now i understood your problem :) look my edit to see the real solution.